# Better way to respond api version in returned JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wonder know how to respond the api version in JSON

because I need to hardcode the version in the response know.

```
returned_data = {
    status: "ok",
    version: "version_num",
    data: symbols
}
render json: Oj.dump(returned_data)
```

It seems not elegent, because I need to put the similar code in each function.

Any  better practice in Rails

#### routes.rb

```
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1) do
      resources :products
    end
    scope module: :v2, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 2, default: true) do
      resources :products
    end
  end
```

#### update (lx00st's suggestion)

```
  before_action :response_template

  private
    def response_template
      @respose = {
          status: "ok",
          version: "v1"
      }
   end

   def   EVERY_METHOD
       @respose[:data] = symbols
      render json: Oj.dump( @respose )
   end
```

Comment: why not to put it in corresponding controller before_action ?

Comment: @lx00st I took your suggestion thanks

Comment: why returning the api version and not putting it in the uri ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating an API you should consider using JSON builders rather than simply rendering JSON the way you are. One nice solution is [ActiveModel::Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). This will allow you define a global serializer which always contains a certain bit of JSON, which will be merged into other responses. It also means you don't have to manually build up your JSON.